# For-loop-nested-in-for-loop via csv.reader() but the outer loop only goes through once?

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv
import numpy as np

with open("D:\PHD\obranking\\demo.csv", mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader=csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    for i, row in enumerate(csv_reader):
        for j, line in enumerate(csv_reader):
            print(i)
            print(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`csv.reader(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) returns an exhaustable iterator. You would have to store the rows in a data structure that allows multiple rounds of iterations, e.g. a `list`:

```
with open("..demo.csv") as csv1, open("..demo.csv") as csv2:
    reader1 = csv.DictReader(csv1)
    reader2 = csv.DictReader(csv2)

    for i, row in enumerate(reader1):
        for j, line in enumerate(reader2):
            # do stuff
        csv2.seek(0)  # reset file handle to start
```

Comment: then if i do so  how would i be able to acess the field values of CSV. as i intend to acess rows column name wise for some comparisions

Comment: also there is a problem i have csv of 1GB that contains 25000 column and 22000 rows so if i load them in list then i will get memory error as this was the reason i droped the use of Pandas which uses data frame as data structure.

Comment: You can have two file handles and reset the inner one after each outer iteration. I added the code.

Comment: @schwobaseggi well first of all i would like to thank you for this. most of my problems are solved but there seems to be a minor glitch see i.e suppose csv has 100 rows then both i and j should vary from 0 to 99 but for every i (which is varying from 0 to 99) j varies from 0 to 100. which should not. can you help fix this also.